# Detect event in Ionic 2 app

Tags: javascript, android, ionic2, sip

All applications go to background due to phone's incoming call. Is there any way to detect in Ionic 2 application when it is going to background and take an action in that event

Comment: Please don't downvote. I have searched a lot regarding this on the Internet, finally had to ask on here

Comment: I didn't downvote last time. And loose your comment because you deleted your post. The problem is: StackOverflow is a place to discuss CODE, not ideas, opinions or recommendations. Thus, it means you have to work before, try to solve your matters and only then return here with your doubts - showing your efforts and path through. We will be pleased to help.

Comment: @statosdotcom thanks for the suggestion. I will try for some code first

Comment: Yeah man, keep it up. You can do it. Best. Suggestion: implement a Service that uses a class that extends PhoneStateListener at your app ;)

Answer (score 0):

I could not comment because of my poor point, but I think I can give guidance.

I think you should subscribe to the platform pause and resume events, you should do something like this.

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  this.platform.pause.subscribe(() => {
    this.connectState = ‘disconnected’;
    this.connected = false;
    this.buttonDisabled = true;
  });
  this.platform.resume.subscribe(() => {
    this.checkConnectivity();
  });
}
```

}

If you need more detail to refer to [this post](https://webcake.co/lets-build-a-ticker-in-ionic-2/) from where I extract the code.